# How to read multiple files with the same prefix in C?

Tags: c

I have a large number of files with prefix info_ _ _ _.txt (eg. info0921,info1231,info0426).
The last four digit is a date with format "mmdd".
I need to write a C program to read all those files, store data into array and do some calculation with it.
I tried to do something like that:

```
for(i = 0; i < Number_of_files; i++){
sprintf(filename, "info%d.txt", i+1);}
```

However, it doesn't work well because "i" does not fit the date format.

Comment: Take a look to glob, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html

Comment: the variant part of the file names is a 4 char field, composed to 2 two char fields..  The first two characters cycle from '01' to '12'.  The second two characters cycle from '00' to '99''  So all the possible file names, of interest, can be produced with two simple nested loops.  Suggest using 'stat()` to determine if a specific file name exists, before calling `fopen()` on that file.

Answer (score 0):

You have two way :

- You try to open all the file that could match your pattern (so approximatively 366 possibility)
- You open the directory where your files are, list all the entry, and for each entry, you see if that's match your pattern.

For the first one, something like

```
for(i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    for(j = 1; j < 31; j++) {
        sprintf(filename, "info%02d%02d.txt", i, j);
        if (!file = fopen(filename, "r")) {
            if (errno != ENOENT) {
                // Real error, log ?
            }
        } else {
            // Yay ! Can use "file" now
            fclose(file);
            file = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

will do.

For the last one, we need to know if you're on Linux-like or Windows.